# Android EPG view in android Mobile (OTT Application)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, epg

Android EPG view in android mobile. I am working on OTT application and I need to show the EPG in my application. I am getting the EPG data from the server.

I got the sample project from the github [https://github.com/korre/android-tv-epg]. I tried implementing this project and I am stuck in loading EPG data from the server. I am using retrofit to retrieve data from the server.

```
fun GetChnlEPG( map: HashMap<String, String>){
    val Call = apiInterface.GetChnlEPG(map)
    Call.enqueue(object : Callback<EPGResponseList>{
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<EPGResponseList>,
            response: Response<EPGResponseList>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                ChnlDetails = response.body()!!.channelDetails as ArrayList<ChannelDetail>

                for (i in 0 until ChnlDetails.size){

                    var EPGResponse: ArrayList<EpgReponse>
                    EPGResponse = ChnlDetails.get(i).epg as ArrayList<EpgReponse>

                    for (j in 0 until EPGResponse.size){

                        if (EPGResponse.get(j).epgAvailable.toString().equals("YES")){

                            ChnlEpgDetails = EPGResponse.get(j).epgDetails as ArrayList<EpgDetailResponse>

                            for (k in 0 until ChnlEpgDetails.size){

                                val ProgDuration = ChnlEpgDetails.get(k).programName

                                Log.d("epgDetails", ProgDuration.toString())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<EPGResponseList>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("EPGResponseList", t.message)
        }
    })
}

//The sample project loads the EPG data as follows 



public class MockDataService {

private static Random rand = new Random();

private static ArrayList<Integer> availableEventLength = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        1000*60*15,  // 15 minutes
        1000*60*30,  // 30 minutes
        1000*60*45,  // 45 minutes
        1000*60*60,  // 60 minutes
        1000*60*120  // 120 minutes
));

private static List<String> availableEventTitles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        "Avengers",
        "How I Met Your Mother",
        "Silicon Valley",
        "Late Night with Jimmy Fallon",
        "The Big Bang Theory",
        "Leon",
        "Die Hard"
));

private static List<String> availableChannelLogos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        "http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg",
        "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png",
        "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png",
        "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png",
        "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/pool.png"
));

public static Map<EPGChannel, List<EPGEvent>> getMockData() {
    HashMap<EPGChannel, List<EPGEvent>> result = new HashMap<>();

    long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i=0 ; i < availableChannelLogos.size() ; i++) {
        EPGChannel epgChannel = new EPGChannel(availableChannelLogos.get(i),
                "Channel " + (i+1), Integer.toString(i));

        result.put(epgChannel, createEvents(epgChannel, nowMillis));
    }

    return result;
}

private static List<EPGEvent> createEvents(EPGChannel epgChannel, long nowMillis) {
    ArrayList<EPGEvent> result = new ArrayList<>();

    long epgStart = nowMillis - EPG.DAYS_BACK_MILLIS;
    long epgEnd = nowMillis + EPG.DAYS_FORWARD_MILLIS;

    long currentTime = epgStart;

    while (currentTime <= epgEnd) {
        long eventEnd = getEventEnd(currentTime);
        EPGEvent epgEvent = new EPGEvent(currentTime, eventEnd, availableEventTitles.get(randomBetween(0, 6)));
        result.add(epgEvent);
        currentTime = eventEnd;
    }

    return result;
}

private static long getEventEnd(long eventStartMillis) {
    long length = availableEventLength.get(randomBetween(0,4));
    return eventStartMillis + length;
}

private static int randomBetween(int start, int end) {
    return start + rand.nextInt((end - start) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the source code of Live Channels (EPG layout included) here: https://github.com/PerfsolTech/EPGView

Our [team](https://perfsol.tech/android-app-development) also created this for OTT application based on RecyclerView so it's really efficient.